# Puzzling behaviour of __name__ variable using multiprocessing (Python 2.7)

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, multiprocessing

Today i was messing with the multiprocessing library, and i noticed something wierd. I was trying to figure out if it was possible to have nested scripts using multiprocessing (a script that uses multiprocessing to run a part of a script which uses multiprocessing to run more parts of the script). To figure this out i started looking at what the `__name__` variable is for the child-scripts, because, if you are familiar with multiprocessing, you know this is going to be a problem

When i wrote a test script, the result surprised me. I wrote this simple script:
    from multiprocessing import Pool

```
def Child(Inf):
    print "Child" + __name__

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Process = Pool(4)
    Process.map(Child, [0,0,0,0])
    print "Parent" + __name__
```

(don't mind the list of four zero's)

The console printed out this:

```
Child__main__
Child__main__
Child__main__
Child__main__
Parent__main__
```

This means that the `__name__` of the child processes is also `__main__`

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
```

This is the part that puzzles me. After testing, it appeared that the child process gets run 4 times, while the if statement only gets run once. This makes sense when reading the code, but the testing shows that all processes are called the same, and the computer shouldn't be able to tell the difference between them, because the child looks at a variable that is no different from the parent.

I am puzzled by this, because i thought i understood how putting in the if statement prevents the child-processes from running the main program as well, but this appears to be untrue.

Am a missing an important clue or is this just something weird i shouldn't be looking at? :p

Regards,
Harm

Comment: Which OS are you using? The `multiprocessing` module uses different methods of creating child processes on different OSs. It's usually only Windows that has the issue with `__main__` getting run multiple times (since it doesn't have  `fork`). In recent versions of Python 3, you can pick between the any of the spawning algorithms your OS supports (in earlier versions, you just get whichever one the devs picked for you).

Comment: „if you are familiar with multiprocessing, you know this is going to be a problem“ – I am familiar with multiprocessing yet I don't know this should be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens is that each process is not fed with the same input.

The parent process will receive and execute the full `.py` file you input while child processes will fork from the parent with certain functions loaded into memory and will be requested to run one specific function instead of running the entire program (which would lead to infinite recursion...).

The fact `__name__` variable is the same is because each child process is a copy of the parent. They are just at different executing points.

---

**On Windows OS:**

I didn't notice until now but somehow Python runs the code again when creating multiple processes on Windows.

On Python 3.5 (maybe other versions of Python 3 too, but I didn't check), it will set the `__name__` variable to `__mp_main__` and avoid the problem.

On Python 2.7, if the value is really `__main__`, the only explanation I have is that the variable is being set after the input code runs. Otherwise the `if` block would be executed as well.

Edit: I just tested on Python 2.7.11 and the `__name__` variable is set to `__parents_main__` before being set to `__main__`. I would not rely on this because it was changed on Python 3 as you can see.

Comment: When learning multiprocessing i was told the "if __name__ == "__main__" was to stop the child-processes from executing the main code. But i guess this is not true then?

Comment: @HarmPrins As I said, creating a child process is a fork operation. It will copy the current process into another one and not execute again the whole python file. This would be a very slow operation. Therefore, there is no need to worry about the child executing anything except for what it was told to execute. If you still don't believe. Try adding a `print` statement prior to the `if __name__ ...` line. It will only run once too!

Comment: weirdly enough if i add a print statement prior to the if statement it prints 5 times

Comment: It (obviously) works the way it should if i use the link, but if i copy the script and run it, it prints it 5 times, and sometimes all messed up too.

Comment: @HarmPrins Are you on Windows? because fork on any unix like OS should work like this.

Comment: @HarmPrins The best advice I can give you is to switch to real OS, but that is not practical. Other than that, check my updated answer...

Comment: I never thought about changing the name variable, but this will probably do the trick. Thanks for taking the time to answer my questions :)

Comment: @HarmPrins I installed Python 2.7 on some windows machine and what I was suspecting is indeed right. I added more info to the answer

Comment: Ah, this explains why it doesn't run the if statement, but does appear to have the same name. Got it, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason the `__name__` should be different at all. It will just give you the name of the module (or `__main__` in case of the program itself) where the code using it resides. And you are always calling it either from the original program or from a forked version of it.